# Apply CSS only when for specific route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

How can I apply CSS rules only when a specific route is served?

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'
import './styles/index.css'
import {
  Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router
} from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './components/App'
import Life from './components/Life'

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/life" component={Life} />
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

In `./styles/index.css` I have some rules for the `body` for instance which I would like to override only when the route `'/life'` is served. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

So, apparently you can just use `require()` inside the React-component.
That means you can do something like this inside your function / class, or outside the component directly under the import statements:

```js
if (window?.location.pathname === '/life')
    require('./styles/index.css')
```

I don't know if one should do that, it seems kind of illegal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can add specific css class based on current route when you need:

```css
.tagClass {
  width: 1200px;
}
```

```js
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let tagPath = '/life' == this.context.location.pathname
    return (
      <div className={tagPath?'tagClass':''} />
    )
  }
}

App.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object,
    location: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

EDIT: according to comment question

You can specify listner for example for App component:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.context.router.getLocation().addChangeListener(listener);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.context.router.getLocation().removeChangeListener(listener);
}
```

or per route handler:

```js
function handler() {
  do something;
}

<Route path='/' component={App}>
  <Route path="foo" component={Foo} onEnter={handler}/>
  <Route path="life" component={Life} onEnter={handler}/>
</Route>
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like to change the body which is not in a component but in the public folder.

Comment: As far as i know react have not access to body. But you can do it manually with plain js.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how i used it to add inline style on specific path

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router';
    
const location = useLocation();
    
<nav style={location.pathname === '/' ? { position: 'absolute' } : null}>
```

Or you can do something like this:

```
const style = {
    position: 'absolute',
    marginTop: '20px',
    background: `${(props) => (props.primary ? 'palevioletred' : 'white')}`,
  };
<nav style={location.pathname === '/' ? style  : null}>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add setInterval in the index.html file *script* tag.

like this:

```
 setInterval(()=> {
if(location == '/'){
..function
}
else if(location == '/about'){
..function
}
}, 1)
```